# In Hexchat or any IRC client, how do I view my past conversation with a person if that person is no longer in the network?

Tags: irc, hexchat

I believe I can message any name directly with `msg <nick> <message>`,  but is there a way to actually view my message conversation / history with that person?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://hexchat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#where-are-the-log-files-saved-to), log files are stored in the following locations:

- Unix: `~/.config/hexchat/logs`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%\HexChat\logs`